# Как привязать страницу к файлу в wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, acf

Есть файл send.php, в который нужно переходить после отправки формы.
Я создал новую страницу, и в файл send.php добавил этот код:

```
<?php
    /*
    Template Name: Custom
    */
?>
```

Затем выбрал этот шаблон в свойствах. Создал поле в плагине ACF, и добавил код получения записей:

```
<?php 

$posts = get_field('new_post');

if( $posts ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $posts as $post): // variable must be called $post (IMPORTANT) ?>
        <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
                ...
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // IMPORTANT - reset the $post object so the rest of the page works correctly ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Возникает ошибка в этой строке:

```
$posts = get_field('new_post');
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_field() in D:\OSPanel\domains\testwp\wp-content\themes\bets\send.php:122 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\OSPanel\domains\testwp\wp-content\themes\bets\send.php on line 122
```

Название проверил, всё правильно. Я так понимаю что я не привязал страницу или ошибся где-то, подскажите как исправить. Спасибо!

Comment: ошибку укажите.

Comment: @Max дополнил вопрос

Comment: нет функции get_field. Вы как запускаете ваш файл? по прямому урлу что ли? Тогда ядро нужно подключить

Comment: @Max да по прямому url, как сделать правильно подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам нужно создать страницу и назвать ее как надо. Выбрать у этой страницы нужный шаблон `Custom` и указать урл. Теперь по заходу на эту страницу все будет отображаться корректно.

Comment: url куда указать нужно?

Comment: Когда страницу создаешь под эту страницу создается урл-страницы.

Comment: перехожу на эту страницу, взял url, вставил в action в форме, переходит не на ту страницу, где я ошибся, подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Если это обработчик формы у тебя то зачем ты создаешь шаблон из него вообще? Что ты пытаешься сделать?

Comment: Может лучше сделать аякс форму и использовать стандартные вп хуки?

Comment: @РашенБеар подскажите, как это реализовать

Comment: Редирект на нее прописать в обработчике после успешной обработки. А если аяксом то редирект прописысать в js-ке - вся разница

Comment: @РашенБеар можете показать пример пожалуйста?

Comment: Меняешь событие success на такое и готово success: `function (response) {
                 window.location.href = "http://bolshoe-spasibo.ru";
            }`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100817/discussion-between-alexander-and--).